# Call Java Webstart 1.6 out of java 1.7 application

Tags: java, java-web-start

I have a bunch of webstart applications, which are programmed and tested under Java 1.6.0_11. For being sure that these applications run as intended, I start them using the javaws.exe of an installed JRE with version 1.6.0_11. This version is only used for starting these applications. The "standard" Java used on my System is always the newest version, in order to get all security updates (etc.).

With version 1.7.0_25 I am not able to call the javaws.exe from my 1.6.0_11 installation anymore. My applications simply do not start. It seems that the 1.7.0_25 webstart does not allow run applications which require an older version. So my problem is: How can I start my applications with the 1.6.0_11 java webstart?

My approach was to build a launcher application, which checks the required java version and calls the appropiate webstart via `Runtime.exec()`. But can I be sure that the called javaws.exe does not use any variables or resources of the installed 1.7.0_25 JRE? It is crucial to me to guarantee the flawless execution of these applications.

Comment: *"With version 1.7.0_25 I am not able to call the javaws.exe from my 1.6.0_11 installation anymore."*  Which I suspect Oracle is thinking is a 'good thing' as otherwise it opens up a whole lot of possibility for apps. to try and demand an older (& potentially insecure) JRE.  I doubt Oracle would fix this even if you could find a document on their site that suggests that it is a bug.

Comment: I do not think that this is a bug. I think it is intended for security reasons. But I still need a way to start my apps with 1.6.0_11 :). Those apps are in a safe network, so the security risk is much smaller.

Comment: Java Webstart can launch a different JVM than itself belongs to, if it knows about it.  Would this happen to be OS X?

Comment: No, only win7 systems